# When boolean turns false, check 5 seconds if it will turn back to true, else do some action

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejs-server

I have in NodeJS a variable that updates every second. I want to monitor it to see if it turns below a certain threshold (e.g. 1000).

If it does go below the threshold, it should wait 5 seconds and monitor if the variable goes back above again. If not, it should return a function. If it does go above, it can stop the times and start monitoring again.

Can't get any code to work.

Not sure if the code below is even in the right direction..!

```
var waitedSoFar = 0;
var imageDisplayed = CheckIfImageIsDisplayed(); //this function is where you check the condition

while(waitedSoFar < 5000)
{
   imageDisplayed = CheckIfImageIsDisplayed();
   if(imageDisplayed)
   {
      //success here
      break;
   }
   waitedSoFar += 100;
   Thread.Sleep(100);
}
if(!imageDisplayed)
{
    //failed, do something here about that.
}
```

Comment: what's your question for us?

Comment: @Frederkun How do i do it in NodeJS? Can't get any code to work...

Comment: Could you share what you've written that's not working?

Comment: @stealththeninja just added it to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function that observe and wrap this variable that change so often. Something as simple as

```
function observeValue(initialValue) {
  let value = initialValue
  let clearEffects = []
  let subscribers = []
  return {
    value: () => value,
    change(val) {
      clearEffects.forEach(oldEffect => oldEffect && oldEffect())
      value = val
      clearEffects = subscribers.map(subscriber => subscriber(value))
    },
    subscribe(listener) {
      subscribers.push(listener)
    }
  }
}
```

is generic enough. The function returns three methods:

- one to get the current value
- one to change the value
- on to subscribe on every value change

I would suggest to leverage the last one to monitor and trigger any side effects.

You can use it like this:

```
const monitor = observeValue(true)

monitor.subscribe((value) => {
  if (value !== false) {
    return
  }

  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('value was false for five seconds')
  }, 5000)

  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  }
})
```

and somewhere else you can change the value with

```
monitor.change(false)
```